# Certificate is Valid, site is insecure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

I have Installed Load balancer for my instance group, properly configured SSL's google certificate, status: active over the correct domains/subdomains
I enter the url via several browsers (chrome/safari), I get the LOCK sign for few seconds and then it turns red with label Not Secure
As shown below, Certificate is Valid, site is not secured.

[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue when my site was connecting to a websocket (http) server.
Imagine the website is `https://example.com` and it connects to a websocket with ip: `157.22.32.11`. the websocket project was running on a vps, and it was a normal nodejs project. i fixed it by buying another ssl for that ip also. (and configured it on nodejs). so you should make sure all of the ips you're interacting with are https.

Comment: `I get the LOCK sign for few seconds and then it turns red with label Not Secure` -> this was exacting in my case too. after a few seconds it was connecting to insecure websocket. you can check it by adding a `test.html` to your domain and visit that. you'll probably see that it will load secure and it shows the lock icon.

Comment: Another potential problem is loading resources via http instead of https. Use the Chrome debugger to review each resource being loaded.